# Trying to understand NumPy's linalg.norm method

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy

I do not understand what this code is doing. X is a matrix which each row of it is an eigenvector of an image. What does the norm do?

```
   # Take an eigenvector and make it into an image
    def vecToImage(x, size = lfw_imageSize):
      im = x/np.linalg.norm(x)
      im = im*(256./np.max(im))
      im.resize(*size)
      return im
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html) is clear on the matter. You are passing None for the ord parameter to linalg.norm() so you get the Frobenius norm.

The code appears to be normalising the input, by dividing by the norm. Then it seems makes a poor attempt to scale to have 8 bit color values. But the code scales to the range 0 to 256 instead of 0 to 255.

However, the first step seems pointless to me. The code could simply read:

```
im = x*(256./np.max(x))
```

But perhaps it should be 255 instead of 256.

Since we've got not context here, I'm reluctant to state that the code is wrong. Only you are in a position to decide that because only you know the context.

Comment: yeah but what's the intuitive thing that is happening in here. I didn't quite understand the math of Frobenius norm...

Comment: I've no intuition for the code. Where did you get it from? I've no idea what the input is. Matrices have eigenvectors and I'm not quite sure how an image has meaning as a matrix. I thought you wanted to know what norm did?

Comment: what does the norm do? what is this calculation for ? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Frobenius_norm

Comment: Broadly speaking a norm is a measure of how large an object is. Abs() is the most common norm for scalars. For vectors you have L1, L2, Linfinity norm and so on. The most common is L2, the Euclidean norm. In your code, the use of norm is pointless.